Why does my Laravel 11 project not use my exception handling?
I'm trying to handle some exceptions from Passport in my Laravel 11 project but for some reason any renderable exceptions (Passport and other exceptions) I add to the ->withExceptions part of my app.php file are being ignored.
I'm testing this using throw new \Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException(); at the start of the method called by my route.
The code that I would expect to work looks like this (within the ->withExceptions part of my app.php):
$exceptions->render(function (\Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException $e, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'error'   => $e->getMessage(),
    ], 403);
});

But this is being ignored, instead using the exception handling of the exception itself. I also tried using the exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException for a non-existant route but this also gets ignored and just uses whatever handling this exception has on it's own. I also tried using $exceptions->renderable instead of $exceptions->render as the Exceptions class passed to ->withExceptions makes it seem like they are interchangeable but this also did not work.
One thing that proves that at least the ->withExceptions section works to an extent is that this does work:
$exceptions->shouldRenderJsonWhen(function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) { 
    return $request->is('api/*');
});

which makes for example Passports MissingScopeException return JSON for API routes. Something else that I also tested to work is $exceptions->respond().
The specific Laravel version I'm using is (as php artisan --version returns) Laravel Framework 11.2.0.
Am I missing something? I'm quite new to handling exceptions in any different way from just using a try/catch block in a piece of code where exceptions could happen so it's possible I'm just misunderstanding this or missing something obvious but I would really appreciate some help here.

Being myself struggling with exception handling in Laravel 11 lately, I found a solution using $exception->renderable as such:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        ...
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
           
        $exceptions->renderable(function (YouException $e) {
            return response()->json([
               'message' => 'message to be displayed.'
            ], 500);
        });       

    })->create();

Took from this article - link - hoping it might help.
